# Laravel eloquent query that reflects updated data based on another table data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

i have done extensive search on this topic, but based on my little knowledge on laravel and eloquent (I'm newbie), I'm totally confused on how to, due to lot of informations I've read.

I have two tables: products and logrent.

```
products->[id, name, stock]
logrent->[id, product_id, user_id, action]
```

when a product is sold, a register is generated on logrent table containing a value for this action (1 for renting, 2 for return of a rented product)

i want to build a eloquent query that reflects that actions on each product, updating a real stock value based on rent / returns on logrent table (in another virtual column if possible)

how I could achieve this?

**EDIT:**

This is what I want, but in Eloquent, could I achieve this? how?

```
select jogos.id, jogos.titulo, (jogos.qt + (select sum(case
fluxos.tipoacao when 2 then 1 when 1 then -1 end) from `fluxos` where
fluxos.jogo_id=jogos.id)) as stock from jogos, fluxos group by id;
```

Comment: So do you generate a new register if a product is returned (with value `2`) or just update the existing register with value `1`? Further, depending on the use-case, I would recommend using [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) for the products in addition to `dates` (like `added_at` and `returned_at`) for traceability.

Comment: the only table that will be updated like a log is the "logrent" (when the products is moved & returned), the products table stock field will remain static on this state. The reason for this query is just for a on-screen report, to keep stock under control

Comment: So basically you might have for example, 5 cars for rent (stock = 5), but to know how many are actually available, you want to query the `logrent` table to determine what's in and what's out?

Comment: exactly that! !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after studying a little bit more, i was able to get it close to what i wanted. i have mounted a sql format for this query, so i able to convert it to eloquent in “raw” format, but i want it in pure eloquent.  There are path to that?

```
$data = \DB::table("jogos")
      ->select("jogos.id", "jogos.titulo", "jogos.qt",  
           \DB::raw("(select 
               sum(case fluxos.tipoacao when 2 then 1 when 1 then -1 end) 
                   from `fluxos` where fluxos.jogo_id=jogos.id) as stock")->get()
```